# Data is not updating in the firebase data. However, it reflects the update in the html page

Tags: angularjs, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bower

This function is used to update and save the data into the firebase database. It's not working properly as I put the breaking at the save function, control doesn't enter the function. The changed data is reflected in the html but not in the firebase database.

```
$scope.editFormSubmit = function(){
            console.log("Updating record");

            //Get ID
            var id = $scope.id;
            console.log(id);

            //Get Record
            var rec = $scope.records.$getRecord(id);
            console.log(rec);
            //Assign Values
            rec.fname = $scope.fname;
            rec.lname = $scope.lname;
            rec.mname = $scope.mname;
            rec.email = $scope.email;
            rec.company = $scope.company;
            rec.phone = $scope.phone;
            rec.city = $scope.city;
            rec.state = $scope.state;
            rec.zipCode = $scope.zipCode;
            rec.conId = $scope.conId;
            rec.DCN = $scope.DCN;
            rec.jobTitle = $scope.jobTitle;
            rec.pAddress = $scope.pAddress; 
            rec.country = $scope.country;
            rec.name = $scope.name;

            // Save Record
            console.log("After assigning values");
            console.log(rec);

            $scope.records.$save(rec).then(function(){
                console.log("Updating values");
            });

            clearFields();

            //hide the edit form
            $scope.editFormShow = false;
            $scope.msg = "Contact Update";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
$scope.records.$save(rec).then(function(){
                console.log("Updating values");
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I changed the code now i am getting this error
Error: Key mname was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead. but i am before saving running this code for every field
if ($scope.fname) { rec.fname = $scope.fname; } else { var fname = ""; }

Comment: i figured it out ...i was running this code if ($scope.fname) { rec.mname = $scope.mname; } else { var fname = ""; } here i was passing undefined i edited my code to this if ($scope.fname) { rec.mname = $scope.mname; } else { var fname = " "; } passing an empty string it worked.. thankyou for your help.